# how can I use a JS function to change an element style in the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need 2 simple JavaScript functions that read and change the color of a div on click.
I don't want to use frames, jQuery any other means but simple html, css, JS.
The code that I have wrote and doesnot work is as follows:

Randomize colours

```
<script>
    var colorArray = {yellow, red, blue, purple};

    function readColor () {
        color = document.getElementById("color");
            }

    function changeColor (color) {
            var randomColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];    
        document.getElementById('color').style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
        var colors = document.getElementById('color');              
            colors.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }       
</script>

<style type = "text/CSS">
    <!--
    #color {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    -->
</style>
```

```
<div id="color" style="border-color: #eee; border-style: solid; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: 200px; padding: 50px; background-color: yellow;" onChange = "readColor ();">
    Aici are loc lupta
</div>  
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;"> 
    <input type="button" name="Change color" value="Change Color" onClick = "changeColor ()">
</div>
```

Comment: The best thing you could do is use firebug or the developer tools in chrome to actually look at what is reported on the javascript console. You'd immediately have found the problem that way.

Comment: you are rigth, but I have tried with chrome and haven't found the mistake.

Comment: In chrome: tools -> developer tools. Run your code as is and it throws a `ReferenceError` on the array line. You could have asked a much more specific question with that information. Just commenting on that because a good debugger like that will save you a _lot_ of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe just changing

```
var colorArray = {yellow, red, blue, purple};
```

to

```
var colorArray = ['yellow', 'red', 'blue', 'purple'];
```

should do it..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/pYc4P/

Comment: Wow thx a bunch. This is actualy embarrasing. I have checked and rechecked the readColor and changeColor function and rewrote them in 6 different modes to no avail. And all this time the mistake was in the variable declaration. It works perfectly now, thx

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not passing in color on the onclick

Should it not read:

```
<input type="button" 
       name="Change color" 
       value="Change Color" 
       onClick = "changeColor (color)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You create `colorArray` as an object, but you are using it as an array.

Try declaring it as an array instead:

```
var colorArray = new Array("yellow", "red", "blue", "purple");
```

Or:

```
var colorArray = ["yellow", "red", "blue", "purple"];
```